# How do you unit test your javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I spend a lot of time working in javascript of late. I have not found a way that seems to work well for testing javascript.  This in the past hasn't been a problem for me since most of the websites I worked on had very little javascript in them.  I now have a new website that makes extensive use of jQuery I would like to build unit tests for most of the system.

My problems are this.

- Most of the functions make changes to
  the DOM in some way.
- Most of the functions request data
  from the web server as well and
  require a session on the service to
  get results back.

I would like to run the test from either a command line or a test running harness rather then in a browser.

Any help or articles I should be reading would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at [JSTestDriver](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/05/22/yet-another-javascript-testing-framework/), written by Misko Hevery, who writes a lot of great articles on testability in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) could help you. It is the official test suite of the jQuery project. As described in the documentation, tests can also be run outside of a browser (with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the interactive nature of Javascript, it's hard to write unit-tests to anything but libraries. To test interactions, we use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which allows you to record interactions and check for expected outcome (such as a DIV appearing or a value changing). Tests can be grouped into suites and ran automatically.

Selenium tests can also be run on the server without a browser with some additional setup.